# Getting stated with NHibernate. Real world project example?

Tags: nhibernate

One of my goals over the next few months is to get familiar with NHibernate and am curious if anyone out there has any suggestions of where to begin. Preferably, I'd like to find a example project that demonstrates what you would see in an in-the-field application.

Comment: Good question. Would be nice if there was a 'petshop' type nhibernate app demonstrating using best practices and typical nhibernate idioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pretty much based the first iteration of an application architecture solely on this article from CodeProject: [NHibernate Best Practices](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx). Also check out this blog: [Ayende @ Rahien](http://ayende.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The author of the NHibernate ASP.NET Best Practices article and went on to produce a newer sample called [Sharp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) using ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

The [nhibernate FAQ blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110227204838/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/Default.aspx) is pretty useful.